# How does char work and how does it relate to the English letters?

Tags: java, char

I have a task as follows:

> Write a method that takes an array of consecutive (increasing) letters as input and that returns the missing letter in the array.
>
> You will always get a valid array. And it will always be exactly one letter missing. The length of the array will always be at least 2.
>
> The array will always contain letters in only one case.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> ['a','b','c','d','f'] -> 'e'
> ['O','Q','R','S'] -> 'P'
> ```

My solution which is really bad is this:

```
public static char findMissingLetter(char[] array) {
    char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

    int offset = 0;
    int point = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
            if (alphabet[j] == array[i]) {
                offset = j;
                point = offset + 1;
                if (alphabet[point] != array[++i]) {
                    System.out.println(alphabet[point]);
                    return alphabet[point];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ' ';
}
```

Now I have found a solution that is really short but I don't understand the code or at least I don't understand how without giving the code the list of possible letters it's able to know which letter is missing:

```
public static char findMissingLetter(char[] array){
    char expectedLetter = array[0];
    for(char letter : array){
        if(letter != expectedLetter) break;
        expectedLetter++;
    }
    return expectedLetter;
}
```

Can someone please explain how char works and why it knows that 'e' is missing even though I haven't provided an array of all the letters?

Comment: read this: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ascii/all

Comment: Just a small general tip: you can initialize a long character array like that from a string. For example: `char[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();`

Comment: yes i used it later in the improvement of my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that you have given is very simple.
You should be familiar that the `char` value is interpretable as an integer value, which is the numeric value of that particular character in the ASCII table.

So, in the solution after taking the initial value of `expectedLetter` (that is the first value in the char array), it checks the numeric value of the characters. If they are the same that means they are the same character, as you are told that the characters are in consecutive order, and in only one letter case. So, it increments the numeric value of `expectedLetter` (which is the next character in the ASCII table or you can say next character alphabetically), and again checks the value until the end of the array.

Comment: I would not say it is changed to `int` value but rather `char` has its decimal value.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I am trying to say. Sorry

Comment: Be careful about those *mistakes* people here are harsh and will get you for little thing like that.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I pretty bad in explaining. So, this helps a lot when people gives me feedback

Comment: but also @VishwasAtrey my first solution can u tell me what are the mistakes in it , although it works it pretty poor

Answer (score 1):

Let's use this example for explanation:

```
['a','b','c','d','f'] -> 'e'
```

In Java, char is a numeric type. When you add 1 to a char, you get the next Unicode code point. In the case of 'A', the next code point is 'B'.

```
public static char findMissingLetter(char[] array){
    char expectedLetter = array[0]; // This code initializes expectedLetter
                                    // with the first character in the array.
    for(char letter : array){
        // The first iteration will always be true. From the second iteration,
        // if the character is not the consecutive one which is expected to be
        // equal to expectedLetter then that letter will be the missing one.
        // Once found, break will close the loop and return that character.
        if(letter != expectedLetter) break;

        // This will increment character consecutively from a -> b -> c -> d -> e
        expectedLetter++;
    }

    return expectedLetter;
}
```